# JSON.NET: How deserialize specific Exception type

Tags: c#, json.net, json-deserialization

Consider the following very simple code.

```
var ex_to_serialize = new Exception("something wrong", new NullReferenceException("set to null"));
var serialized_ex = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ex_to_serialize);

var deserialized_ex = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Exception>(serialized_ex);
Console.WriteLine($"Type of inner exception: {deserialized_ex.InnerException.GetType().Name}");
```

And voilá... the inner exception type is `Exception` instead of `NullReferenceException`.
So I searched SO and find lot of example with custom `JsonConverter` used for desrialization (as the serialized JSON contains `ClassName` property, which could be used to create the specific type). So I wrote one (only `ReadJson` is present for simplicity, rest is as usual).

```
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
        return null;
    var json_object = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Load(reader);
    var target_type_name = json_object.Value<string>("ClassName");
    var target_type = Type.GetType(target_type_name);
    var target = Activator.CreateInstance(target_type);
    serializer.Populate(json_object.CreateReader(), target);
    return target;
}
```

And pass this converter when calling `DeserializeObject` function above.
This time, I get exception:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot populate JSON object onto type 'System.Exception'. Path 'ClassName'

As far as I dug into the Newtonsoft.Json code, it seems the "problem" is that `Exception` is `[Serializable]` and `ISerializable` so it uses SerializableContract which does not support populating object. But here I end in desperation :-(. Could someone help me?

(The example above is just for simplicity, I need to serialize and deserialize my own exceptions, which are far more complex. Newtonsoft.Json version 11.0.0.2 used.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are forgetting TypeNameHandling setting.[[Typehandling](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm)]
So please fix your code like the following, it will work properly

```
var ex_to_serialize = new Exception("something wrong", new NullReferenceException("set to null"));

var serialized_ex = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ex_to_serialize,new JsonSerializerSettings{TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All});

var deserialized_ex = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Exception>(serialized_ex, new JsonSerializerSettings{TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All});

Console.WriteLine($"Type of inner exception: {deserialized_ex.InnerException.GetType().Name}");
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. But... what in the case I cannot change the serialization process (e.g. it happens on the unaccessible server), so I get json without `TypeNameHandling`? Is there any way how to handle the behaviour? I still have the item "ClassName" in the serialized json, so I can find the target type, but I do not know how to pass the information to the deserialization process.

Comment: If you you have no whatsoever chance to change the json you manipulate then all you can do is either write a custom binder or customserializer :)

Comment: CustomeBinder has no sense, because it doesn't contains any context, and CustomSerializer? You mean the CustomConverter? That's what I tried in the question...